# explain the for loop and output of this C code please

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, operators, decrement

Can someone please explain this C code to me. This was one of the questions asked in my exam to find the output.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int r()
{
    static int num = 7;
    return num--;
}

int main()
{
    for(r(); r(); r())
        printf("%d\n",r() );
}
```

I can't understand how the for loop is working (condition and increment/decrement statement) and how this code gives this output.

```
Output:
5
2
```

Comment: Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the `return num--` line in `r()` and on the `printf()` statement. Step through the code, and you should see exactly how that output is produced.

Comment: Are you sure your code as written? It seems that since `num` is initialized in each call to `r()`, `r()` will always return `7` (post decrementing it after the `return`).

Comment: @daShier yes the code is right and it is using 'static int num' so it will not always 'return' 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the loop

```
for(r(); r(); r())
```

the function `r` is called in the init expression

```
for(r(); r(); r())
    ^^^
```

Its static variable `num` is decreased and becames equal to `6`.

Then the condition of the loop is checked

```
for(r(); r(); r())
         ^^^
```

Again the function is called and its static variable becames equal to `5`.

Within the call of `printf`

```
printf("%d\n",r() );
```

there is called the function `r`. Because within the function there is used the post-decrement operator then the function returns 5 but the value of `num` becames equal to `4`. So the returned value 5 is outputted.

Then the third expression of the loop is evaluated.

```
for(r(); r(); r())
              ^^^
```

`num` becames equal to 3.

Again the condition is checked and num becames equal to 2.

```
for(r(); r(); r())
         ^^^
```

In the call of `printf` the returned value 2 is outputted but within the function `r` the value of num is decremented and becames equal to 1.

After that the third expression of the loop is evaluated.

```
for(r(); r(); r())
              ^^^
```

num becames equal to 0.

This value is returned in the condition by the function r. Within the function the static variable now is equal to -1.

As returned value is 0 the loop stops its iterations.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand.
>   As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
>   is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it)...

and

> 3 The postfix -- operator is analogous to the postfix ++ operator,
>   except that the value of the operand is decremented (that is, the
>   value 1 of the appropriate type is subtracted from it).

Comment: Thanks for such good explanation

Answer (score 3):

A `for` loop of the form

```
for(init; condition; repeat) {
    body;
}
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
init;
while (condition) {
    body;
    repeat;
}
```

So your given statement is equivalent to:

```
r();
while (r()) {
    printf("%d\n", r());
    r();
}
```

The first call to `r` initializes the static variable `num` to `7`. It then returns this value while also decrementing it to `6`. This return value is not used.

Then the `while` condition is tested. This call to `r()` returns the value `6` while decrementing `num` to `5`. Since this is non-zero, the condition succeeds, so we go into the loop body.

Then it executes `printf("%d\n", r());`. This call to `r()` returns the value `5` while decrementing the variable to `4`. The return value is printed by `printf()`, so we see `5`.

Then we call `r()` as the repetition operation. This decrements `num` to `3`, and the return value is ignored.

Then we go back to the `while` condition. This decrements `num` to `2` while returning `3`. This is non-zero, so we go into the body.

Then we execute `printf("%d\n", r());`. As on the previous iteration, `r()` returns the current value of `num` while decrementing it to `1`, so `2` is printed.

Then we call `r()` as the repetition operation. This decrements `num()` to `0` and returns `1`, but the return value is ignored.

We go back to the `while` condition. This time, `r()` returns the current value `0` while decrementing it to `-1`. This time, the return value is zero, so the loop stops.

Comment: Thanks, Sir! I need to study about `init` more I think.